# Curve Fitting Two Series Python

Tags: python, scipy, series, curve

I am trying to curve fit a sinusoidal shaped data set, but I a getting an error saying 'Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'. How do I correctly pass my two series for X and Y values to fit the curve?

```
def objective(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * math.sin(b - x) + c * x**2 + d

# choose the input and output variables
x = moon_data["Full Moon"].values.squeeze()
y = moon_data["Full Moon Price"].values.squeeze()
plt.scatter(x,y) # This works!

# curve fit
popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, x, y) # This is the line causing the error
```

Moon Data is a Dataframe that I turned into a Series using .squeeze(). The original data looks like this (first 3 rows):

|  | Full Moon | Full Moon Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1488 | 2020-05-07 | 10001.0 |
| 1489 | 2020-06-05 | 9617.17 |
| 1490 | 2020-07-05 | 9083.8 |

Comment: post a format of your moon_data? Is it a data frame?

Comment: @ShuvashishRoy yes, it is - I updated the post to show the first 3 rows of the dataframe

Comment: Did you see what I said in the answer about the array which you can't assign into `math.sin(b - x)` ? You can multiply but not subtract.

Comment: @ShuvashishRoy I did try modifying my code as you suggested, but got the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

Only Size 1 Arrays Error is a TypeError that gets triggered when you enter an array as a parameter in a function or method which accepts a single scalar value. So, the problem in your function is here: `math.sin(b - x)`

`x` can only be a single scalar value but what you are assigning is `moon_data["Full Moon"]` as `x` which is an array. Change it to `np.sin(b*x)` it will work but I guess you want something else so you will have to change the function accordingly.

You can't put datetime object inside sin(). Math.sin()  takes a single number, not array. So, use np.sin() instead. Convert the `moon_data["Full Moon"]` column to datetime then toordinal so that you can put it into sin.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def objective(x, a, b, c,d):
    return a * np.sin(b*x) + c * x**2+d 

# choose the input and output variables
x = moon_data["Full Moon"]
y = moon_data["Full Moon Price"]
X=pd.to_datetime(x).apply(lambda x:x.toordinal())

plt.scatter(x,y) # This works!

# curve fit
popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, X, y)
```